# Simple tuple in Python

Tags: python, tuples, slice

Would someone be able to explain in simple English why this happens when I try to index the below... I thought I should be getting back 45, 49, 52, 55 as my answer? I'm sure I am missing something here...

```
times = (43, 45, 49, 52, 55)
print(times[1:4])
(45, 49, 52)
```

Comment: I have a general understanding of indexing, but why doesn't the 55 show up? When I do print(times[0:4])  it returns 43,45,49,52 which is what I would expect. But when I start from 1 in the indexing it doesn't seem to follow the same logic?

Comment: Copied from the top answer: `a[start:end] # items start through end-1`

Comment: Thanks, I can see what you mean; however the logic behind it though I don't understand. Why not give me 45,49,52,55?

Comment: Because `start` is 1 and `end-1` is 3.

Comment: Thanks, but why the end-1 - is there a logical reason why it does this?

Comment: Because Python developers defined slices that way? I don't know. But for what it's worth, the behavior is consistent e.g `range(1, 4)` does not include 4.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept it for what it is (I just wish I knew the logic why they do this). Thanks vaultah appreciate it :-)

Comment: @Alvis you may considering referring to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm